# QTextDocument issue with HTML links

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextdocument

I'm building a simple Marquee widget using PyQt5 to display some news that are supposed to scroll from left to right. The news text is supposed to contains links, so the user can click on them and read the full news post (on a website). I'm using a QTextDocument to render news titles (together with href urls) in HTML: while the HTML is rendered perfectly, I'm unable to click on the generated href tag. Here below the code I'm using:

```
class MarqueeLabel(QLabel):
    px = 0
    py = 0 
    paused = False
    qthread = None
    refresh_msec = 30 
    textDocument = None
    textWidth = 0
    timer = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(433, 40)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            background: transparent;
            color: #484848;
        }
        """)

    def parseFeed(self):

        class FeedParser(QThread):

            msignal = pyqtSignal(list, list)

            def run(self):
                try:
                    feed = feedparser.parse(URL)
                except Exception, e:
                    pass
                else:
                    feedhtml = []
                    feedtext = []
                    for item in feed['entries']:
                        feedhtml.append('%(TEXT)s (<a href="%(LINK)s">read more</a>)' % dict(LINK=item['link'], TEXT=item['title']))
                        feedtext.append('%s (read more)' % item['title'])
                    self.msignal.emit(feedhtml, feedtext)

        self.qthread = FeedParser(self)
        self.qthread.msignal.connect(self.setMarqueeText)
        self.qthread.finished.connect(self.start)
        self.qthread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(list, list)
    def setMarqueeText(self, feedhtml, feedtext):
        ## FIXME: the 1.1 multiplier should not be here, but without the text goes on 2 lines!
        plaintext = ' - '.join(feedtext)
        self.textWidth = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(plaintext).width() * 1.1
        self.textDocument = QTextDocument(self)
        self.textDocument.setUndoRedoEnabled(False)
        self.textDocument.setUseDesignMetrics(True)
        self.textDocument.setTextWidth(self.textWidth)
        self.textDocument.setHtml(' - '.join(feedhtml))
        self.px = self.width()
        self.py = self.height() - self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(plaintext).height() - 6

    def start(self):
        if self.textDocument:
            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.scrollText)
            self.timer.start(self.refresh_msec)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.paused = True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.paused = False
        return QLabel.event(self, event)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        if self.textDocument:
            p = QPainter(self)
            p.translate(self.px, self.py)
            self.textDocument.drawContents(p, QRectF(self.rect()))

    def scrollText(self):
        if not self.paused:
            if -self.px > self.textWidth:
                self.px = self.width()
            else:
                self.px -= 1
        self.repaint()
```

And this is a screenshot which shows the HTML rendered correctly, despite the fact that clicking on the URL does nothing? Any hint?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `QLabel` this should be trivial. Just use the suitable `Qt::TextInteractionFlags`. In your case that would be `Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse`.

The documentation clearly tells you:

```
enum  Qt::TextInteractionFlags
flags Qt::TextInteractionFlags

...
Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse      4   Links can be highlighted and activated with the mouse.
Qt::LinksAccessibleByKeyboard   8   Links can be focused using tab and activated with enter.
...
```